# Nodemon syncronous task execution before restarting

Tags: node.js, gulp, ecmascript-6, babeljs, nodemon

I'm running gulp as build tool for my nodejs server. I have one issue with nodemon (Nodemon is a utility that will monitor for any changes in your source and automatically restart your server. ), since i'm not able to execute a gulp task to transform my ecmascript 6 code before the server restarts.

This is my code. Nodemon documentation says that syncronous task execution is possible with node version 0.12.0. My node version is 0.12.6. Anyone noticed the same problem or knows how to fix?

https://github.com/JacksonGariety/gulp-nodemon

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var noDemon = require('nodemon');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');

gulp.task('server', ['transformES6'], function () {
  noDemon({
    script : 'server/dist/server.js',
    ext : 'js',

    env : {
      PORT : 8000
    },
    ignore : [
      './node_modules/**',
      './server/dist/**'
    ],
    tasks : ['transformES6']
  }).on('restart', function () {
    var now = new Date();
    console.log('server is restarting: ' + now.getHours() + ' Hours, ' + now.getMinutes() + ' Minutes, ' + now.getSeconds() + ' Seconds');
  });
});

gulp.task('transformES6', function () {
  return gulp.src(['./server/**/**/**/**/*.js', '!./server/dist/'])
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./server/dist/'));
})
```

Thanks in advance!

Greetings Mauro

Comment: You did not point out, what exactly doesn't work. What do you get now? What do you expect?

Comment: So what i want is transforming my code everytime before nodemon restarts. Browsers can't intepretend ecmascript 6, so i need to transform it to ecmascript 5. In nodemon object property tasks, i defined transformES6, which should work according to gulp-nodemon documentation. Whenever i start this gulp task for the first time, it's transforming my code once, but whenever i make a change, it's not transforming anymore, but it does restart my nodemon server, while my code is not transformed. I expected that my code was transformed into ecmascript 5. Hope this will make things more clear.